# Visual Studio 2015 CUIT Output Link Now Missing

Tags: c#, output, visual-studio-2015

When Running CUIT in Visual Studio 2015. Originally when I created tests and ran them from the Test Explorer after the test was completed I had an "Output" Link below my test status and Elapsed Time. The newer tests I have created no longer have this option. I had valuable Writeline Information that I was using to follow the test now that I can no longer see.

Thought it would be worth mentioning but not sure if its related. I noticed this happened once my original project was upload from a local file to the Source Control folder, any test added after that no longer had the output but older tested i created before still have the option to select the output link.

Please help as I have researched extensively and can't seem to find a solution. I apologize but can't give any pictures due to sensitive information, but I am trying to be descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 0):

*FacePalm*  Probably would have helped if I had added the Writeline to the actual test I was calling. Checked all but the obvious SMH...

Comment: I would recommend deleting the question if it was a simple error which is not reproducible, rather than adding what should be a comment as an answer.  This question and answer combination will be of little use to others in the future, and could possibly generate down votes if left.